# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x82DA0002): Exception from HRESULT: 0x82DA0002

Tags: .net, exception

Does anyone know what this means?

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x82DA0002): Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x82DA0002    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate
>   method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
>   at Midden.cMidden.OnFileChanged(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) 
>   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.OnDeleted(FileSystemEventArgs e)    at
>   System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32 action,
>   String name)    at
>   System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32 errorCode,
>   UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* overlappedPointer)    at
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

Comment: Well, at the least, it means you got an exception.

Any way you can post the code for the code you are executing when the file system watcher events are fired?  That would go a long way to helping us help you.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception.aspx): (hope it's helpful)

The exception that is thrown when an unrecognized HRESULT is returned from a COM method call.

The common language runtime transforms well-known HRESULTs to.NET exceptions, enabling COM objects to return meaningful error information to managed clients. The HRESULT to exception mapping also works in the other direction by returning specific HRESULTs to unmanaged clients. For mapping details, see How to: Map HRESULTs and Exceptions.

When the runtime encounters an unfamiliar HRESULT (an HRESULT that lacks a specific, corresponding exception), it throws an instance of the COMException class. This all-purpose exception exposes the same members as any exception, and includes a public ErrorCode property that contains the HRESULT returned by the callee. If an error message is available to the runtime (obtained from the IErrorInfo interface or the Err object in Visual Basic, or in some cases from the operating system), the message is returned to the caller. However, if the COM component developer fails to include an error message, the runtime returns the eight-digit HRESULT in place of a message string. Having an HRESULT allows the caller to determine the cause of the generic exception.

Although you can use the COMException class to return specific HRESULTs to unmanaged clients, throwing a specific.NET exception is better than using a generic exception. Consider that managed clients as well as unmanaged clients can use your.NET object, and throwing an HRESULT to a managed caller is less comprehendible than throwing an exception.

Answer (score -2):

for us at work that indicates little or not diskspace on server

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: erm yes it is an answer it means check your disk space on the server! we were getting it all over the place today and figured out that it was due to lov disk space on the server that was causing the exact same error the author posted, we made some room and the error went away, its that simple... i dont get why you think my answer isnt an answer. he asked do you know what this means... obviously he got this error and wants a solution which i gave if its the same as mine, yes i didnt describe the error i give you that ;)

Comment: Expand your answer to explain that in your post then; you can [edit] it.